# How to check whether a list exists?

Tags: python, vertices

How to check whether the list (of vertices) exists?

I want to append a new vertex to a list or create one if it does not exists.

```
if verts is not exist:
    verts = [[0,0,0]]
    edges = []
    faces = []
else: verts.append([1,1,1])
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to test whether a variable exists, you can follow [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843277/how-do-i-check-if-a-variable-exists-in-python) and see if it's in `locals()` or `globals()`.  So your code would be

```
if 'verts' in globals() or 'verts' in locals():
    verts.append([1,1,1])
else:
    verts = [[0,0,0]]
    edges = []
    faces = []
```

Answer (score 1):

You could initialize your list like:

```
verts = None
```

...

```
if verts is not None:
    verts = [[0,0,0]]
    edges = []
    faces = []
else: 
    verts.append([1,1,1])
```

Also you could initialize everything:

```
    verts = []
    edges = []
    faces = []
```

and simply invoke append later on (without having the need to do any tests):

```
    verts.append([1,1,1])
```